# Isn't the word `polymorphic` missing in §1.3.7 (N4140)?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, language-lawyer

Isn't the word `polymorphic` (in parentheses) below, missing in **§1.3.7 dynamic type**?

> [ Example: if a pointer (8.3.1) p whose static type is “pointer to
>   class B” is pointing to an object of a (`polymorphic`) class D,
>   derived from B (Clause 10), the dynamic type of the expression *p is
>   “D.” References (8.3.2) are treated similarly. —end example ]

Comment: _"class D, **derived from B** ..."_ already implies polymorphism.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not necessarily. In fact, the point is that the type doesn't have to be polymorphic in the quote above.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The question is a good one, even though the OP is wrong. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, even if we wanted to require polymorphism in this case, it would make more sense to impose that requirement on class `B`, not `D` (and as a consequence of that `D` would become polymophic as well).

Secondly, the general concept of *dynamic type* does not in any way rely on polymoprphism.

Comment: But if B is not polymorphic, isn't it wrong to say that the expression *p has type D? For me *p has type B in this case.

Comment: @François-Marie Arouet: "Type"? What type are you talking about? Static of dynamic? If `p` physically points to a `D` object, then static type of `*p` is `B`, but dynamic type of `*p` is `D`, by definition.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the concept of dynamic type. Could you clarify?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: Maybe the problem is rather your understanding of polymorphic. What do you think a polymorphic class is, and why do you think it is required in the definition of 'dynamic type'?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Forget about polymorphism for the moment. What is a dynamic type? I don't know.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet: You gave the definition of 'dynamic type' in your question. The problem is you don't understand it, because you think the word `polymorphic' should be in there, which is why I think it would be more instructive to get your definition of polymorphic.

Comment: @AnT You finally got it with your comment above. `What type are you talking about? Static of dynamic? If p physically points to a D object, then static type of *p is B, but dynamic type of *p is D, by definition.`.Now it's clear. Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ Standard (10.3 Virtual functions)

> 1 Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented
>   programming. A class that **declares or inherits a virtual function is
>   called a polymorphic class**.

In the quote you cited there is not required that the classes would be polymorphic that is that they had a virtual function. So including this word would not be correct.

The quote gives a general definition of the dynamic type irrespective of whether the classes are polymorphic or are not..

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the definition of "dynamic type" needs that qualification. If you look through the rest of the standard, you'll see that when the static and dynamic types are different, that doesn't automatically imply that the expression behaves like the dynamic type. This is specified to **only** happen when the static type is polymorphic. For example, see [expr.typeid]/2-3:

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers
>   to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic
>   type) to which the glvalue refers. If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary `*` operator to
>   a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the `typeid` expression throws an exception (15.1)
>   of a type that would match a handler of type `std::bad_typeid` exception (18.7.3).
>
> When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers
>   to a `std::type_info` object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-
>   pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the
>   expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

In paragraph 3 you can see that it specifically says "static type". That's because the static and dynamic types can still differ, but only the static type matters because it's not polymorphic.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding the concept of a dynamic type. Could you clarify?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet You could, if you wanted, imagine it as "the last constructor called". If you have `D d; B* b = &d;` then even though `*b` is statically of type `B`, the `B` object it refers to is really part of an object of type `D`, because the `B` constructor call was followed by a `D` constructor call.

Comment: But what constructor call are you talking about here? The object `d` is already contructed, in the initialization of the pointer `p` in `B* b = &d;`.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet Yes, I mean that constructor call, the one used to initialize the object `d`. Since `b` points to that object, `*b`'s dynamic type is `D`.

Comment: I finally understood your answer, when you wrote: `In paragraph 3 you can see that it specifically says "static type". But I still don't understand why can't a prvalue be polymorphic?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet The glvalue/prvalue distinction in C++ echoes the lvalue/rvalue distinction in C, where instead of "rvalue" the standard says "value of an object". A prvalue is not a reference; it is conceptually identical with the value of an object. It doesn't have a dynamic type because it doesn't *refer* to anything, unlike a glvalue. (Note that you can force a prvalue to survive longer than a normal temporary by binding it to a reference, but then the reference's name becomes an lvalue.)

Comment: Great explanation in your last comment. Thanks (+1)